# How to handle EmbededEntity Google Datastore field

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

I've a datstore kind in GCP  as below:
Kind name: "Test"

Fields are:

- name --   string
- date_of_birth -- date & time --Nullable
- category -- EmbededEntity -- Nullable

The value of the category filed is as follow:

```
{"technology":{"start_date":"2020-01-10",   "end_date":"2020-03-31",    "desgnation":"teamlead",    "project_handle":2},"management":{"start_date":"2020-01-10",    "end_date":"2020-03-31",    "desgnation":"trainee", "project_handle":2}}
```

Like in Java : Map

In Go, I've used Go google datastore library to fetch the record from datastore and used the following struct

```
type Test struct{
    Name string `datsttore:"name"`
    DOB Time.time   `datastore:"date_of_birth"`
    category interface{} `datastore:"category"` 
}
```

When category field value is present as mentioned in above example then struct is populating properly but if category value is null then from datastore library it throws a panic from the following highlighted execution.

[image]

Comment: Could you take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post the actual text of the error you received, not a screenshot of code?  It helps people in the future to be able to find this question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you want to have a null-able value for category you will need to make it a pointer.  The [docs](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Property) show using `*Entity` for a null-able embedded entity.

The error you are seeing is what is documented in '[Loading Nulls](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#hdr-Loading_Nulls)'

Comment: The problem is datastore single field is emdedEntity type for some entity and for some entity it is null type. How we can handle it with single  struct property ?

Comment: An inner struct is an embedded entity.  So either it needs to be a pointer so that it is nullable or not a pointer and not nulable.

Comment: How I can use map like data as a inner struct. Data is like  map[string]anotherstruct